# How can i call phtml file into cms page used widget?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I have a phtml file mw/news/slider.phtml so how can I call it into cms page by used widget?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should to create the widget with 'CMS Static block' type and assign the static block with `{{block type="[block_type]" template="[template_file]"}}` directive to it? But I think that it would be better to use the `{{block type="[block_type]" template="[template_file]"}}` directive directly in the CMS Page?